# Flattening TypeScript typings or interfaces?

Tags: typescript, angular, definitelytyped

As a TypeScript developer, I have become too used to "Duplicate identifier" issues when working with `.d.ts` files.

Most recently, this occurred because I needed both the typings (`.d.ts` files) of Angular 2, and Parse.

Angular 2 doesn't distribute their `.d.ts` files through `DefinitelyTyped`, so I had to fetch Angular 2 through NPM which includes the source files as well.

Now, Parse's `.d.ts` files come from `DefinitelyTyped`. Fine - so far, so good.

The issue then arises because both of these libraries depend on Node JS typings. The Node JS typings of Parse are located in the `typings` folder, whereas the Node JS typings of Angular 2 are located in a subfolder under `node_modules/angular2`.

This gives me a huge amount of duplicate identifier issues when compiling.

#### So, the big question(s)

- Can I flatten `.d.ts` files so that it doesn't have duplicates somehow?
- Can I somehow make the TypeScript compiler ignore duplicate interface definitions?

Comment: Can you provide a link for the `Parse` you mean?

Comment: It is just the DefinitelyTyped definition for "Parse".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official tool to flatten `.d.ts` files or any other I'm aware of. There are many reported issues for your (or similar) problem:

- [typings from angular2 conflict with project typings](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5807)
- [Type definition conflict with jQuery TSD](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5459)
- [Conflict between Mocha and Jasmine typings.](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5395)
- [Error on $ in angular-protractor.d.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4725)

Angular team is [working on the issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5807#issuecomment-164678165).

As a workaround, I would simply comment out `///<reference>` comments that cause your errors and wait for a bugfix.