# Angular 2 TypeScript using SignalR

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, webpack, signalr

I'm trying to set up an Angular 2 application to use Microsoft's SignalR. I've been following [this tutorial](http://chrome-extension://klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg/suspended.html#uri=https://blog.sstorie.com/integrating-angular-2-and-signalr-part-2-of-2/), which although it's good I don't like the fact that jQuery and SignalR are loaded into the application via script tags in the index.html file and also the fact that both libraries do not use their respective Type Definitions.

So with that in mind I've been trying to include jQuery and SignalR in my application using node modules and the respective Type Definitions. I've searched the correct type definition files to use through Microsoft's [TypeSearch](http://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/).

I'm only including jQuery in my application because of SignalR's dependency on jQuery.

**jQuery**

I first started with installing the jQuery module in my application which I've had to add in the Webpack configuration as well. After this was set up I'm being faced with a "conflict" issue because of Protractor. This is described on [Aurelia JS Rocks' website](http://www.aureliajsrocks.com/error-variable-must-type-cssselectorhelper/). Although it suggests uninstalling the protractor typings I tried our another solution for now [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39361876/2312637). I don't know if this is the best solution.

**SignalR**

With regards to SignalR I'm a bit stuck - so far it seems there's no "official" node module provided for SignalR. I'm not sure whether I should include Microsoft's SignalR Javascript Library by downloading the file and including it in my application.

The issue is that I have installed the Type Definitions for SignalR. But now I'm not sure how to go about actually using SignalR since when I type `$` or `jQuery` I'm not being suggested `.connections` for example - which makes sense as this is not part of the jQuery library.

I'm sure that I might be misunderstanding something with regards to getting it "set up". What's the best way to go about using SignalR in an Angular2 TypeScript application?

Comment: Do you have idea of HUB?

Comment: The issue is not the HUB.. as I mentioned in my question "I have installed the Type Definitions for SignalR. But now I'm not sure how to go about actually using SignalR since when I type `$` or `jQuery` I'm not being suggested `.connections` for example"

Comment: // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        chat = $.connection.YourHUBNAME; to create a proxy you can use

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's a startup code you can use.

**C#**

```
//create an interface that contains definition of client side methods
public interface IClient
{
    void messageReceived(string msg);
}

//create your Hub class that contains implementation of client methods
public class ChatHub : Hub<IClient>
{
    public void sendMessage(string msg)
    {
        //log the incoming message here to confirm that its received

        //send back same message with DateTime
        Clients.All.messageReceived("Message received at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

**HTML**

Add reference to `script` files of **`jQuery`** and **`signalR`**.

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/jquery.signalR.min.js"></script>

<!--this is the default path where SignalR generates its JS files so you don't need to change it.-->
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

**JS**

You need to install **TypeScript definition file for SignalR and jQuery**. If you're using `TypeScript 2`, you don't need to add reference to `index.d.ts` file while using it. Just install the typings using following commands.

```
npm install --save @types/jquery
npm install --save @types/signalr
```

With all the setup done, you can write a simple `TypeScript class` to handle the logic for sending and receiving messages.

```
export class MessageService {
    //signalR connection reference
    private connection: SignalR;
    
    //signalR proxy reference
    private proxy: SignalR.Hub.Proxy;


    constructor() {
        //initialize connection
        this.connection = $.connection;
        
        //to create proxy give your hub class name as parameter. IMPORTANT: notice that I followed camel casing in giving class name
        this.proxy = $.connection.hub.createHubProxy('chatHub');

        //define a callback method for proxy
        this.proxy.on('messageReceived', (latestMsg) => this.onMessageReceived(latestMsg));

        this.connection.hub.start();
    }
    
    private onMessageReceived(latestMsg: string) {
        console.log('New message received: ' + latestMsg);
    }

    //method for sending message
    broadcastMessage(msg: string) {
        //invoke method by its name using proxy 
        this.proxy.invoke('sendMessage', msg);
    }
}
```

I'm using the above code, obviously modified to my needs, and it works fine.

---

**Update 1:** This is a pretty old answer and things have changed a lot since then. Install `jQuery` and `SignalR` using `npm` and then load them using `angular.json` file, like this:

1- Install `npm install jquery signalr`

2- Load in `angular.json -> projects -> your-app -> architect -> build -> options`

```
scripts: [
  "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", 
  "./node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.min.js"
]
```

Thanks and credits to [Robert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58469815/3621001) for update.

Comment: That's very helpful! Thanks a lot... one thing is that even though I'm using TypeScript 2.0.9 it seems that I still have to use the refer to the `index.d.ts` file. Without the reference I'm getting errors when I try to call `SignalR` for example.

Comment: @DanielGrima: sounds strange n you're welcome. if this solved your problem, please mark it as answer so that it is helpful for somebody else in future.

Comment: Yeah it is strange.. I'll investigate further and see what happens

Comment: I managed to solve the issue I had with the type definition reference... I had to add `"signalr"` in the `types` array in the `tsconfig.json` file, once I did that problem was solved :) Not sure if it's supposed to be added automatically.. anyway for now all okay :)

Comment: i'm getting this error: Type 'SignalR' is not assignable to type 'Connection'.
  Property 'proxies' is missing in type 'SignalR'. for  this.connection = $.connection;    Any ideas?  I already installed the typings via npm.

Comment: @jaypman: try changing the line `private connection: SignalR.Hub.Connection` to this `private connection: SignalR`

Comment: Thank you @SyedAliTaqi :)  It works now with your suggestion.

Comment: After TypeScript definition file for SignalR and jQuery, I start getting lots of error TS1005: Build:',' expected. errors in \node_modules\@types\jquery\index.d.ts File.

Comment: @Pankaj: which version of `@types/jquery` are you using? try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44672035/angular4-npm-jquery-error-ts1005-expected) solution.

Comment: Just downloaded the latest ones, I am using @types/jquery version 3.2 and my jquery is version 3.2.1

Comment: I'm getting an error on this line `this.proxy = $.connection.hub.createHubProxy('myhub');` it says: Error TS2322 Type 'HubProxy' is not assignable to type 'Proxy'. any clue?

Comment: Changing the definition `private proxy: SignalR.Hub.Proxy;`
 to `private proxy: HubProxy;` solved it partially  but I'm still getting errors elsewhere that doesn't seem related

Comment: guys I am getting $.connection is undefined in typescript only, works ok in index.cshtml. any ideas?

Comment: I'm getting these errors when I use above code.    Cannot find name 'SignalR'.Cannot find namespace 'SignalR' Cannot find name '$'. What should I do ?

Comment: @Vasanth: have you installed the typings for `jQuery` and `SignalR`?

Comment: If I have a console application as server, where should I put the url to the server in my client side? Thank you.

Comment: @Ibanez1408: didn't try that yet. I believe all of the config is inside generated *js* file of SignalR. for a console application, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140164/signalr-console-app-example) might help.

Comment: At least for me, 1) `private connection: SignalR;` should be `private connection: SignalR.Hub.Connection;` 2) all `.hub` should be removed. 3) `declare var $: any;` is needed ahead. 4) The HTML section is not applicable and can be ignored.

Answer (score 8):

@Syed Ali Taqi's answer is basically OK but not perfect(even not working if you miss configuring ts compiler). Here's my steps for newest Angular(version 8 as of my writing):

1. Install jquery and signalr run time libs: `npm install jquery signalr`
2. Tell Angular to load the libs at run time as if they were in the `<script></script>` tag by configuring angular.json :

   ```
   projects:
     <your-app>:
       architect:
         build:
           options:
             ...
             scripts: [
               "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
               "./node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.min.js"
             ]
         ...
         test:
           options:
             ...
             scripts: [
               "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
               "./node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.min.js"
             ]
   ```
3. Install types for jquery and signalr so that the ts compiler can recognize them: `npm install @types/jquery @types/signalr --save-dev`
4. Tell the ts compiler to load the types *by default* by editing the `types` section of tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.spec.json:

   ```
   compilerOptions:
     types: [..., "jquery", "signalr"]
   ```

OK, all done! Happy SignalR coding!

```
let conn = $.hubConnection("<base-path>");
let proxy = conn.createHubProxy("<some-hub>");
...
```

Note: never try to `import ...` from `jquery` explicitly in your code, as said by https://angular.io/guide/using-libraries#using-runtime-global-libraries-inside-your-app

For more info on angular.json configuration, see https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config