# Angular4 - npm jQuery error TS1005: ',' expected

Tags: jquery, angular

My project was ok until moment I installed jquery packages via:

```
npm install jquery
```

and:

```
npm install -D @types/jquery
```

After this I got some errors and decided to use jQuery via script tags in index file. So tried to uninstall installed packages:

```
npm uninstall jquery
npm uninstall @types/jquery
```

Also tried with `sudo` and/or `--save` and/or `--save-dev` like:

```
sudo npm uninstall jquery --save-dev
```

Uninstalation progress went well, according to the console:

> removed 1 package in 2.199s

But I still received error while tried to `npm start`:

> node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(47,40): error TS1005: ','
>   expected. node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(2370,40): error
>   TS1005: ',' expected. node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(2372,46):
>   error TS1005: ',' expected.
>   node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(2483,23): error TS1005: ','
>   expected. 
>   and so forth...

Then noticed that `nodemodules/@types` still contains `jquery` so I deleted it manually, but then:

> node_modules/@types/angular-animate/index.d.ts(6,1): error TS2688:
>   Cannot find type definition file for 'jquery'.
>   node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts(6,1): error TS2688: Cannot find
>   type definition file for 'jquery'.
>   node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts(86,18): error TS2304: Cannot
>   find name 'JQueryStatic'.
>   node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts(2004,46): error TS2304: Cannot
>   find name 'JQueryStatic'. src/app/search.component.ts(14,19): error
>   TS2339: Property 'target' does not exist on type '{}'. npm ERR! code
>   ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 2 npm ERR! angular-tut@1.0.0 build: `tsc -p
>   src/` npm ERR! Exit status 2

So as I understand after I installed jQuery, I also changed other node_modules (@types/angular) ?

**UPDATE:**

---

As @selemmn recommended I tried to delete catch:

`rm -r node_modules`

`npm cache clean` After this got:

> npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues
>   and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you
>   want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify'
>   instead. npm ERR! npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the
>   entire cache, rerun this command with --force.

So:

`npm cache clean --force`

`npm install`

And got this error:

> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of
>   null

So as from [gitHub](https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues/298), remvoved package-lock.json and again removed packages and cache.

And now trying `npm start` brought me to the starting point:

> node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(47,40): error TS1005: ','
>   expected. node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(2370,40): error
>   TS1005: ',' expected. node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(2372,46):
>   error TS1005: ',' expected.
>   node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(2483,23): error TS1005: ','
>   expected. node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(2484,17): error
>   TS1005: ',' expected. node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(2485,17):
>   error TS1005: ',' expected. and so forth

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-tut",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Example project from an angular.io guide.",
  "scripts": {
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:upgrade": "tsc",
    "serve:upgrade": "http-server",
    "build:aot": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json && rollup -c rollup-config.js",
    "serve:aot": "lite-server -c bs-config.aot.json",
    "build:babel": "babel src -d src --extensions \".es6\" --source-maps",
    "copy-dist-files": "node ./copy-dist-files.js",
    "i18n": "ng-xi18n",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~4.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.26",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/angular": "^1.6.20",
    "@types/angular-animate": "^1.5.7",
    "@types/angular-cookies": "^1.4.4",
    "@types/angular-mocks": "^1.5.10",
    "@types/angular-resource": "^1.5.9",
    "@types/angular-route": "^1.3.4",
    "@types/angular-sanitize": "^1.3.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "babel-cli": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-angular2": "^0.0.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine": "~2.4.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rollup": "^0.41.6",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^8.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "source-map-explorer": "^1.3.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

---

I dont get it - I delete all packages - `rm -r node_modules`. Also delete `paskage-lock.json` and cache as well and if I try to search for "jquery" in the whole project, nothing is found, but after I run `npm install`, `package-lock.json` file being created with:

```
"@types/jquery": {
  "version": "3.2.3",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/jquery/-/jquery-3.2.3.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-3/ETl4JziXnuFIx6W+WB7BzPGRnYH2O/AFKafSOulabMyAhRfv/oboEO2yytsRvzZDiLFODuydYbr7C0kudB9w==",
  "dev": true
},
```

So where this jQuery is coming from??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've fixed the same error by adding belows to my package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
...
"@types/jquery": "^2.0.42",
...
}
```

Thanks for your UPDATE2, so can I find this @types/jquery lib

Answer (score 15):

I finally made it work by upgrading the Typescript version from 2.2.0 to 2.3.

That was a HUGE heading.

I hope this will help someone.