# How to silence the TypeScript compiler with duplicate identifiers?

Tags: typescript, webstorm

How to silence the TypeScript compiler with duplicate identifiers with WebStorm?

See below:

[image]

tsconfig:

```
   {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
}
```

Regards,

Sean

Comment: This is a common issue with Angular2 lately.  I was answering a similar question with the same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34627194/99256.

Comment: I think, I've had a similar problem before and the problem was the typescript module system interfere with the references. It really depends on how you use the module structure (*internal* [namespaces] or *external* modules) and if your use a reference to this file directly.
I think the problem is neither TSLint, Webstorm nor your configuration. Maybe you could post an module example and your reference file or your tsd.d.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should move your tsconfig.json in the root directory of your real code files.

In that case, the file is higher in the directory tree and attempt to validate the node_modules.